# Automatically assign name to a new record

Tags: javascript, algorithm, airtable

looking for a way to automatically update a cell value when a record is created.
I use Airtable, and I would like to automatically assign a developer to the newest record.

Ex. I have 3 developer, christophe/thomas/hugo

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Using basic algorithm, but the issue is that when there is a new Biz Dev, we have to manually add him to the arrayBizDev and add a new switch case:

`let arrayBizDev = ["Christophe", "Thomas", "Hugo"]
let nbBizDev = arrayBizDev.length;
let bizDev = "";

switch (nbRdvPris % nbBizDev) {
case 0:
bizDev = "Christophe";
break;
case 1:
bizDev = "Thomas";
break;
case 2:
bizDev = "Hugo";
break;
default:
console.log(`erreur`);
}

output.set('Business Developper', bizDev);`

Comment: If this is meant to be additional information for the question, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72631613/edit) the question directly to add it, then delete this answer.  Don't use an answer for clarification.  Also please read about how to [format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).